# Learning the path of the captured image in onActivityResult method

Tags: android, android-camera

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {      
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.picture_choice_activity);

    Button takePictureButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.takePictureButton);
    takePictureButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v){
            Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            startActivityForResult(intent, IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        }
    });
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if(requestCode == IMAGE_CAPTURE){
        if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){
            // I should get the path here
        }else if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED){

        }
    }
}
```

In the above code I am trying to get the path of the captured image. I should not use EXTRA_OUTPUT to specify a custom path to save the image. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kindly check, http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera.html#intents

`MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT` : This setting requires a Uri object specifying a path and file name where you'd like to save the picture. This setting is optional but strongly recommended. If you do not specify this value, the camera application saves the requested picture in the default location with a default name, specified in the returned intent's Intent.getData() field.

so, check the `Intent data` in `onActivityResult()`

Answer (score 3):

Use this in ur onActivity result

```
final Uri contentUri = data.getData();
final String[] proj = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
final Cursor cursor = managedQuery(contentUri, proj, null, null, null);
final int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
cursor.moveToLast();
final String path = cursor.getString(column_index);
```